# Find and select part of SQL string

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, find

I'm using SQL Server and I would like to create a column (Temp) that uses part of another String (Description). I want to retrieve the GB information from Description:

The description field can look like:
`'blah blah blah 100GB blah'` - I'm interested in the `'100GB'`.

The problem is that the amount of GB and placement in the string can vary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use regular expressions for that, but then you would also need to use CLR functions. However, you could specify the exact regular expression you want to use so it would be more accurate.

http://www.yumeidearmas.com/2013/10/02/regular-expressions-in-sql/

If you want an "easier" solution, maybe you could also use PATINDEX to find the index of the "GB". will be 100 the only number on the string (or you could also have some more?)?

```
declare @string nvarchar(100) = 'blah blah blah 100GB blah'

select SUBSTRING(@string,  PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @string), PATINDEX('%GB%', @string)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @string))
```

This case will work for your example, but if the format is different for some reason (there is no number, or there are 2 numbers, etc.) will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes that's one of my problems, the field can have all types of information in it, here are 2 examples from the db: 'BROADBAND ACCESS PLAN 50GB' and 'iPad Tablet 3GB $50'. If only I could do a search for GB and then select x characters left from that placement until the first immediate space.

Comment: In that case, I think you would need to use the CLR functions :( and then create a regular expression "([0-9]+)GB", in that case, the $1 would return just the number

Comment: Sorry, it should be this one: SELECT dbo.RegExReplace(@string, '(.*?)([0-9]+)GB(.*?)', '$2')

Comment: You could do what I wrote before that "it takes the first number" and then it takes the value that we have between the number and "GB", however, for something like:
'blah blah blah 100 blah 150GB'

It would take "100 blah 150"

The problem is, that we don't know "how many characters" we need to take before, it could be "3GB" or it could be "150GB"...

Comment: thank you for showing me how to solve this. I'm reading your blog now and hopefully be able to solve my problem after I understand more about CLR functions!

Comment: Using reg. expressions will allow you to even have  'blah blah GB blah 100 blah 150GB' and it would return '150' ignoring the 'GB' and "100" because they don't have the right format.

Comment: You're welcome! let me know if you have any issue but once you have it, you could use the .dll in any project so you only do this once.